# What is the best practice for sending a file from Server to mobile client?

Tags: c#, mobile, blob, binary-data, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using **SQL Server** and **ASP.Net Core WebAPI** as my backend. I want to send files to the mobile app from my server.

What is the best practice for doing this?

Send the file as a byte array. The mobile app has to write the business logic to process the file based on content type and display in the app.

OR

Convert BLOB to actual file based on file's content type and share the server path to the mobile app. The mobile app can download and display the content.
Note: When to delete the actual file stored on the server is a concern here.

Which one is the best one? Any other suggestions?

Thank in Advance.

Comment: Welcome! Sadly your question is too broad and opinion-based. [ask].  Wishing you well

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, the file should be in your database or on your filesystem, not both. If you're going to do something like query the blob from the database, write it to the filesystem, and then return a URL to that written file, don't add it to the database at all, and simply store it on the filesystem in the first place.

Second, a byte array isn't something that has to be "converted", as the name implies, it's just raw bytes. That's what the client receives from the server regardless of the source. (In other words, if you read from the file system, the client is still getting streamed raw bytes.) The mime type the server returns along with the file tells the client how to interpret the bytes.

Comment: Ok. Got it. If the file is stored in DB as a blob, then the only option available to transfer the file to the client (mobile app) is as byte array, right?